# Can I pass in several strings to one parameter in Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I am trying to pass several strings into one parameter called '@Portfolio', and use the LIKE clause.  Is that possible?  Something like this.

```
Declare @AsOfDate varchar(10)
Declare @PID varchar(5)
Declare @Portfolio varchar(20)
Declare @sqlCommand  varchar(max)
Set @AsOfDate = '04/30/2018'
Set @Portfolio = 'Treasury Investment,CASH,Derivatives,Wholesale Funding'
Set @PID = 'I.A.6'

...etc...

WHERE ((Tgt_DO.PID like ' + '''' + @PID + '''' + ' AND Tgt_DO.Portfolio like ' + '''' + @Portfolio + '''' + ' And Tgt_DO.AsOfDate = ' + '''' + @AsOfDate + '''' + '))'
```

I am on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: you can build your query using `IN` if you would like to see the one result

Comment: This is not dynamic SQL. You are just concatenating values in a static way.

Comment: If you had your parameters on a list or array you could build a SQL statement using a while statment or similar to produce an `IN (...)`.

Comment: Ahhh!  The IN Clause.  Got it.  Thanks!!

Comment: @ryguy72, like "TheI mpaler" said, that is not a dynamic sql, ignore it if you have already noticed that xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comments... since you use `LIKE` in some cases you'll need to concate the `%`

```
where
    Tgt_DO.PID like '%' + @PID + '%'
    and Tgt_DO.Portfolio like '%' + @Portfolio + '%'
    and Tgt_DO.AsOfDate = @AsOfDate
```

This *could* bring back unintended results since `@Portfolio` is a comma separated string. I would use a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) or split them into a temp table or table variable using a splitter, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577523/6167855)